# Do I need 2x6 studs in my basement energy walls?

Tags: drywall, concrete, basement, framing, foundation

I am starting to think about finishing my walk out basement. I am in the southeast USA on top of sand mix soil.

For insulating full-height concrete foundation walls, do I need 5.5" studs like the builder previously used for exterior wall framing above grade in the basement?

[pics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alrSY.jpg)

Comment: Also, before you map out the project and determine what questions to ask, start by asking why you think you have no moisture issues.  A small amount of moisture seeping through unfinished concrete walls and floors will evaporate and may not cause any problems.   But if you cover them up with anything, preventing the evaporation, you may have moisture issues.  Or not ... but you can't just guess. Start by looking for existing questions and answers on that topic.  Briefly, tape sheets of clear plastic to sections of wall and floor and see if they turn darker, especially after rain.

Comment: @jay613, thanks for the concern. I don't see any cracks in the foundation walls and I've never seen any water in the basement - I'm in the southeast and it RAINs big time here. I understand it can be a big issue. When you say "cover them up" do you mean if I place a rigid insulation? The rigid insulation cannot serve as a vapor barrior?

Comment: I mean tape a sheet of plastic about 2ftx2ft to the wall and one to the floor, taped all around the edges.  Wait a few days.  See if the concrete behind the plastic is a little damp compared to the rest of the room.

Comment: Think about where you want to put plumbing, wiring, switches and outlets and whether you're ok with surface mounting.   If you want a standard finished look with recessed everything, you'll want to use at least 2x4.

Comment: @jay613, thank you for the answer. I definitely will do 2x4 or more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

2x6 studs were used to allow R-19 or better insulation in the framed portion of the exterior walls. Unless you want that much insulation below, 2x4 walls are adequate (and standard in my northern climate). Heat loss is much less below grade, so R-13 is usually considered enough.

You could even put 2x2 furring strips directly on the concrete and install 1½" foam panels between if that meets your insulation needs and any plumbing or electrical space requirements.